How to prevent scroll position reset during route changes in Angular with custom scrollable container?
I'm working on an Angular project where I have a custom scrollable container inside a layout component that holds nested routes. I'm encountering an issue where, during route transitions, the scroll position of my custom container resets to the top, and I want to preserve the scroll position.
Here's what I’ve tried so far:

I've disabled scrollPositionRestoration in the Angular router configuration, but the issue persists.

I'm handling the scroll position manually by listening to the scroll event on the custom container and saving the scrollTop value.

On route change, I'm restoring the saved scroll position in the NavigationEnd or Scroll router events.

However, after the route transition, the scroll position briefly restores to the saved value but immediately scrolls to the top, causing an undesirable flicker, since i am using angular router animation. the leaving component first jumps to top than the flicker happens after tgat entering component shows up.


My Requirements:

The scroll position of the container (dashboardLayoutContent) should remain where it is when navigating between routes.

I want to manually set the scroll position to 0 only when required, not automatically on route change. so that the flicker not occurs during animation.


How can I prevent the custom scrollable container from resetting its scroll position during route changes? How can I fix this issue without using workarounds like setTimeout that cause more problems?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
public onScrollDashboardLayoutContent(event: Event): void {
    const target = event.target as HTMLDivElement;
    this.scrollPosition.set(target.scrollTop);  // Save the current scroll position
}

private scrollPositionRestorationHandler(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
        this._router.events.subscribe((event) => {
            console.log(event);  // Log router events to debug

            if (event instanceof Scroll || event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                const contentContainer = this.dashboardLayoutContent().nativeElement;

                // Restore the saved scroll position
                const savedScrollPosition = this.scrollPosition();
                contentContainer.scrollTop = savedScrollPosition;

                setTimeout(() => {
                    contentContainer.scrollTop = 0;
                }, 10);
            }
        })
    );
}

<div
        #dashboardLayoutContent
        class="dashboard-layout-content"
        (scroll)="onScrollDashboardLayoutContent($event)"
    >
        <div
            class="dashboard-layout-outlet"
            [@.disabled]="isLoadingFirstTime()"
            [@routerSlideInOut]="_contexts.getContext('primary')?.route?.snapshot?.data"
        >
            <router-outlet />
        </div>
    </div>

